# Error: NG0201: No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0201 While testing with Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am new to testing with Karma and Jasmine in Angular. I have looked for the error and it comes up due to modules not being imported or declared properly, But in my use case, I am testing the app. I believe I have provided the imports, so what exactly am I missing here?

This is my component.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatAutocomplete } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { map, Observable, startWith } from 'rxjs';

interface Options {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-primary-auto-complete',
  templateUrl: './primary-auto-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./primary-auto-complete.component.css'],
})
export class PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() placeholder: string = 'Start typing here';
  @Input() options: Options[] = [];
  @Input() ngStyle: { [Klass: string]: any } | null = null;

  @Input() autoSelectFormControl = new FormControl('');

  // @ts-ignore
  filteredOptions: Observable<Options[]>;

  // @ts-ignore
  @ViewChild('auto') autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.autoSelectFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value || ''))
    );
  }

  // Clears the option if it is a wrong one
  onBlur = () => {
    if (!this.autocomplete.isOpen)
      this.options.some((item) => {
        if (item.key === this.autoSelectFormControl.value) return true;
        return false;
      })
        ? null
        : this.autoSelectFormControl.setValue('');
  };

  private _filter(value: string): {
    key: string;
    value: string;
  }[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter((item) =>
      item.key.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
}
```

This is the HTML file.

```
<mat-form-field
  [ngStyle]="ngStyle"
  appearance="outline"
  class="primary-autoSelect"
  floatLabel="always"
>
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <input
    type="text"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    matInput
    [formControl]="autoSelectFormControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    (blur)="onBlur()"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
      [value]="option.value"
    >
      {{ option.key }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error *ngIf="autoSelectFormControl.hasError('required')">
    {{ label }} is required
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="!autoSelectFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Please select a value from the list {{ label }}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is the testing file.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormControl, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatAutocomplete } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatOption } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatError, MatFormField, MatLabel } from '@angular/material/form-field';

import { PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent } from './primary-auto-complete.component';

describe('PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent', () => {
  let component: PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent,
        MatAutocomplete,
        MatFormField,
        MatLabel,
        MatOption,
        MatError,
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When I run the test file, I get this. `Error: NG0201: No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0201`.

What is the right way to test such a component?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you're using `formControl`, I am thinking you need to change the import from `FormsModule` to `ReactiveFormsModule`. in the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Comment: But I am not using ReactiveFormsModule, Am I?

Comment: I think `[formControl]` relies on the `ReactiveFormsModule` to work.